# Confidence interval for difference

Tags: probability, confidence-interval

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two i.i.d. random variables with zero mean and finite second moment. Let $l_1,l_2 \leq 0$ and $u_1,u_2 \geq 0$ be constants. Set
$$
P(l_1 \leq X_1 \leq u_1) = p_1 \quad \text{and} \quad P(l_2 \leq X_2 \leq u_2)=p_2.
$$
Does it follow that
$$
P(l_1 - u_2 \leq X_1 - X_2 \leq u_1 - l_2) \geq (p_1+p_2)/2?
$$

Comment: The inequality is true for the normal and uniform distribution

Comment: I think $P(l_1-u_2\le X_1-X_2\le u_1-l_2)=P(l_1\le X_1\le u_1,l_2\le X_2\le u_2)$, which is greater than or equal to $p_1+p_2-1$ in general but if $X_1,X_2$ are independent then the last probability is $p_1p_2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the intersection of events
$$
\{l_1\leq X_1\leq u_1\}\cap \{l_2\leq X_2\leq u_2\} = \{l_1\leq X_1\leq u_1\}\cap \{-u_2\leq -X_2\leq -l_2\}
$$
*implies* the event (and does not equal to, in general)
$$
\{l_1-u_2 \leq X_1-X_2 \leq u_1-l_2\}
$$
then 
$$
\mathbb P(l_1-u_2 \leq X_1-X_2 \leq u_1-l_2) \color{red}\geq \mathbb P(\{l_1\leq X_1\leq u_1\}\cap \{l_2\leq X_2\leq u_2\}) = \mathbb P(l_1\leq X_1\leq u_1)\cdot \mathbb P(l_2\leq X_2\leq u_2)=p_1p_2.
$$
Since 
$$
0\leq (p_1-p_2)^2 = p_1^2+p_2^2 - 2p_1p_2,
$$
we have 
$$
p_1p_2 \color{red}{\leq} \frac{p_1^2+p_2^2}{2} \color{red}{\leq} \frac{p_1+p_2}{2}
$$
As you can see, there are the opposite inequalities to what you need. So the inequality is most likely wrong in general.

Take, for example, two i.i.d random variables $X_1,X_2$ with discrete distribution 
$\mathbb P(X=0)=\mathbb P(X=2)=\frac16$, $\mathbb P(X=1)=\frac23$. Then 
$$
\mathbb P(0.9\leq X_1\leq 1.1)=\frac23, \quad \mathbb P(0.9\leq X_2\leq 1.1)=\frac23
$$
and 
$$
\mathbb P(0.9-1.1\leq X_1-X_2\leq 1.1-0.9)=\mathbb P(-0.2\leq X_1-X_2\leq 0.2) 
$$
$$= \mathbb P(X_1=X_2) = \frac{1}{6^2}+\frac{2^2}{3^2}+\frac{1}{6^2} = \frac12 < \frac{\frac23+\frac23}{2}
$$

Comment: Ok, thanks. Just a small typo I noticed: It should say $P(X=1)=2/3$.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I corrected it.